# RDF standard datatype for currency

Tags: rdf, currency, ontology

I'm developing an ontology for banks and I need to attach datatype properties that are filleed with currency amount. Is there any standard way to do this.

Thanks Luciano

Comment: I doubt there is a standard but you may look at how GoodRelations represent currency amount. schema.org also has various concepts related to monetary values, partly (or totally) inspired by GoodRelations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use xsd:double

Moreover, because you are working in a banking system, maybe you will find this information helpful: http://www.currency2currency.org/EUR#